# How to show default value instead of not showing the whole record?

Tags: sql

Can you tell me how to show a default value instead of not showing the whole record at all? I have a project for university to do tables for a repair service. Each order should have 2 operator's ids - the operator who did the diagnostic and the one who did the repair. Currently I have 10 orders. Each of them has an operator who did the diagnostic. But only 3 of 10 have an operator who did the repair. So, 7 of the records I need didn't go through the repair operation and there is no repair operation related to the order. By executing the query below I get only 3 records out of 10 because 7 of the records didn't go through the repair operation. How can I fix that so I get all 10 records so the ones that didn't go through repair get a default value (for example NULL)?

For clarifications:
OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 2 means diagnostic
OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 1 means repair
If I remove the last row of the query I get all 10 records.

```
SELECT 
    MODEL AS "Model", 
    ENTRY_DATE AS "Entry date", 
    CLIENT_ID AS "Client ID",
    DEVICE_TYPE AS "Device type",
    OO1.OPERATOR_ID AS "Operator diagnostic",
    OO2.OPERATOR_ID AS "Operator repair"
FROM 
    P_DEVICE D, 
    P_ORDER O, 
    P_DEVICE_TYPE T, 
    P_ORDER_OPERATION OO1, 
    P_ORDER_OPERATION OO2
WHERE 
    D.DEVICE_ID = O.DEVICE_ID AND
    D.DEVICE_TYPE_ID = T.DEVICE_TYPE_ID AND
    (OO1.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OO1.OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 2) AND
    (OO2.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OO2.OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 1)
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and _easier to convert to outer join_ if needed.

Comment: I had more errors with it. But if that's the only way to execute the query properly, I will try to switch to it.

Comment: Implicit joins are outdated since 30 YEARS!

Comment: Well, I don't care much about the syntax. I have an assignment to do and I'm trying to do it. For now I definitely don't need SQL for job. But if JOIN is going to resolve my problem, I will try it.

Comment: "Well, I don't care much about the syntax" -> This an extreme problem when asking SQL questions because the syntax is the most deciding thing in SQL. Your obsolete comma-separated list of tables works like an INNER JOIN, but if you want to get null values for not matching records, you likely need to use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I got what I wanted with this query, finally. Thank you so much for clarifying about INNER and LEFT JOIN. Appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me, after few hours of try-catching =)

```
SELECT
    T.DEVICE_TYPE AS "Тип техниката",
    D.MODEL AS "Модел техника",
    O.ENTRY_DATE AS "Дата на постъпване",
    O.CLIENT_ID AS "Клиент ID",
    OO2.OPERATOR_ID AS "Служител диагностика ID",
    OO2.DESCRIPTION AS "Заключение след диагностика",
    OO2.DATE_END AS "Дата диагностика",
    OO1.OPERATOR_ID AS "ID служител, поел поръчката",
    OO1.DATE_END AS "Дата на приключване"
FROM
    P_ORDER O 
        LEFT JOIN P_ORDER_OPERATION OO1 ON O.ORDER_ID = OO1.ORDER_ID AND OO1.OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 1
        LEFT JOIN P_ORDER_OPERATION OO2 ON O.ORDER_ID = OO2.ORDER_ID AND OO2.OPERATION_TYPE_ID = 2
        INNER JOIN P_DEVICE D ON O.DEVICE_ID = D.DEVICE_ID
            INNER JOIN P_DEVICE_TYPE T ON D.DEVICE_TYPE_ID = T.DEVICE_TYPE_ID
```